# Open Hyper-V Linux VM Full Screen

Tags: hyper-v, fullscreen

I have a Centos 7 Linux VM running in Hyper-V. I have adjusted the kernel line to set it to the host's resolution of 1920x1080. This works well, in the sense that the VM opens in a window of that size. But what I would really like to do is have the Hyper-V window open in full screen mode. Once launched I can set the VM Window to full screen from the menu, but it would be preferable to just have it launch in that mode.

I've tried setting properties on the launch icon to 'maximized' and fiddling with launch command settings, but these are ignored; the Hyper-V window itself cannot be set into full screen mode unless it is already running a VM.

How to do this?

Comment: Possibly related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hyperv-virtual-machine-not-covering-full-screen/79330f73-ac1b-4ad9-9266-ff53842f7dd7

Comment: I have Hyper-V here. I am fairly sure this is a limitation of Hyper-V.  You also cannot set a Hyper-V machine to variable resolution like one can with VMware Workstation.

Comment: @John True, but a similar solution as proposed at Answers Microsoft above - editing Grub to the desired resolution - should work for the purpose.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. I've already edited Grub to make the screen full size. The problem is that the Hyper-V window itself remains as a window; it's that window that I want to launch in full-screen mode, without the window decorations. I can do that using the 'View' menu once the VM launches, but I'd much prefer to just have it happen when launched.